# How can I access nodes properties of a Sankey chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, sankey-diagram

Using the google charts [Sankey Diagram](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey#configuration-options), I want to set my self the positions of the nodes: The normal behaviour of a Sankey diagram is that every nodes emerging from others nodes must be aligned on the same vertical line:

[image]

My aim is to copy this Sankry Diagram :

[image]

As you can see, nodes emerging from the same previous node are not on the same  level.

My questions:

Is it possible to access each node property ? From what's google is displaying on its tutorial, one can only modify the behaviour of **every** nodes :

```
var options = {
  width: 600,
  sankey: {
    link: { color: { fill: '#d799ae', fillOpacity: 0.8 } },
    node: { colors: [ '#a61d4c' ],
            label: { color: '#871b47' } },
  }
};
```

If not possible with Google Charts, do you know another web framework that could let me customise the diagram as described ?

Comment: I believe you can customize the [style](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) of each node but not the placement...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at sankeybuilder.com and it's Node Lock feature. SankeyBuilder automatically creates Sankey diagrams from a .TAB separated file that you upload.  You could then move Nodes to your desired look/layout and then save their positions.  You can then load that diagram in the future or share it with other users via a unique URL.  If the underlying data changes you can update the data without affecting the originally stored Node Positions. Optionally you can reset the diagram to the original layout; which allows you to try different Node positions.