# How do I set specific node positions for a google sankey chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to set specific node positions for a google chart sankey diagram but on the google chart guides (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey) it says that node positions are determined automatically. The only thing I can change is increase the sankey.iterations property but I don't want to increase it too much since the higher it is the longer the sankey takes to load.

Is there a way around this to achieve specific node positioning?

I want to do this since sometimes the long node labels end up overlapping a bit as in this picture:
[overlapping node labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oANCx.png). Also, the nodes sometimes go in between like the picture
[sankey diagram with overlapping links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gquz1.png)

Instead I'd like to put the 'exception' node in the middle, at the same level, as the blue node (if possible) and the links to not be overlapping as much as it is here: [sankey diagram with little overlap between links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSOak.png)

A similar question was asked before ([How can I access nodes properties of a Sankey chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977219/how-can-i-access-nodes-properties-of-a-sankey-chart)) but I need to create the sankey with google charts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think this is not possible with google charts.

It works with plotly though: https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/

[image: screenshot of code and output with plotly]